# How to Rename a Class in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I can find all tags of a given class with:

```
soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'Foo'})
```

How do I change the class from 'Foo' to 'Bar'? My class names are unique so I don't have to worry about changing something in the text, so I tried

```
for changethis in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'Foo'}):
     changethis.find("Foo").replaceWith("Bar")
```

No luck. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
    <div class="foo bar"></div>
    <div class="cabbage foo"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
""")

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='foo'):
    pos = div.attrs['class'].index('foo')
    div.attrs['class'][pos] = 'bar'    

print soup
```

Gives:

```
<html><body><div class="bar bar"></div>
<div class="cabbage bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
</body></html>
```